# KVO AVAudioPlayer not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, key-value-observing

I am trying to observe the "currentTime" property of AVAudioPlayer. But the method isn't even being called... I need it to set the position of a UISlider..
But it's not working. Here's the relevant code:

```
[audioPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentTime" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:nil];


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"%@", change);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe currentTime is not KVO compliant check the header.

In any event, you can just start a NSTimer at your desired frequency and update your UI that way.